# Laravel API only works on a specific route, others throw a 404 error

Tags: laravel, api

Update: 
running `php artisan route:clear` fixes the issue, but only partly.
After I run the command and successfully consume the API, the route I call disappears from the route list cache again, and it forces me to run the command again. I have no idea why this is happening.

---

I'm trying to consume a Laravel API I set up but I can only consume one of the three routes available for some reason, the other two drop a 404.

```
Route::post('/login', 'API\UserController@login'); //this works

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::post('/roles/all', 'API\RoleController@getAll'); //this doesn't work - error 404
    Route::post('/permissions/all', 'API\PermissionController@getAll'); //this doesn't work - error 404
});
```

The routes point to the correct place, the functions exist, and the call I'm making through Postman has the correct parameters (url example: 'http://localhost:8000/api/roles/all', GET call, auth token in Authorization field).

It also doesn't matter if I put the routes inside or outside the middleware (in case it had something to do with the oauth2 token or the middleware itself having issues).

Here's an example of one of the functions I'm trying to call:

```
public function getAll()
{
    $role = Role::all();
    return response()->json(['role' => $role], 200);
}
```

Edit: here's the output of php artisan route:list

```
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                                                      | Name                              | Action
                           | Middleware |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | POST     | api/login                                                |                                   | App\Http\Controllers\API\UserController@login  
                           | api        |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/authorize                                          | passport.authorizations.authorize | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController@authorize       | web,auth   |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/authorize                                          | passport.authorizations.deny      | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\DenyAuthorizationController@deny        | web,auth   |
|        | POST     | oauth/authorize                                          | passport.authorizations.approve   | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ApproveAuthorizationController@approve  | web,auth   |
|        | POST     | oauth/clients                                            | passport.clients.store            | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@store                  | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/clients                                            | passport.clients.index            | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@forUser                | web,auth   |
|        | PUT      | oauth/clients/{client_id}                                | passport.clients.update           | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@update                 | web,auth   |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/clients/{client_id}                                | passport.clients.destroy          | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ClientController@destroy                | web,auth   |
|        | POST     | oauth/personal-access-tokens                             | passport.personal.tokens.store    | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@store     | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/personal-access-tokens                             | passport.personal.tokens.index    | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@forUser   | web,auth   |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/personal-access-tokens/{token_id}                  | passport.personal.tokens.destroy  | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\PersonalAccessTokenController@destroy   | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/scopes                                             | passport.scopes.index             | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\ScopeController@all                     | web,auth   |
|        | POST     | oauth/token                                              | passport.token                    | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken        | throttle   |
|        | POST     | oauth/token/refresh                                      | passport.token.refresh            | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\TransientTokenController@refresh        | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | oauth/tokens                                             | passport.tokens.index             | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@forUser | web,auth   |
|        | DELETE   | oauth/tokens/{token_id}                                  | passport.tokens.destroy           | Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizedAccessTokenController@destroy | web,auth   |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/cache                            |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\CacheController@index                  | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/cache/{telescopeEntryId}         |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\CacheController@show                   | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/commands                         |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\CommandsController@index               | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/commands/{telescopeEntryId}      |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\CommandsController@show                | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/dumps                            |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\DumpController@index                   | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/events                           |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\EventsController@index                 | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/events/{telescopeEntryId}        |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\EventsController@show                  | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/exceptions                       |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\ExceptionController@index              | telescope  |
|        | PUT      | telescope/telescope-api/exceptions/{telescopeEntryId}    |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\ExceptionController@update             | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/exceptions/{telescopeEntryId}    |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\ExceptionController@show               | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/gates                            |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\GatesController@index                  | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/gates/{telescopeEntryId}         |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\GatesController@show                   | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/jobs                             |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\QueueController@index                  | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/jobs/{telescopeEntryId}          |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\QueueController@show                   | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/logs                             |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\LogController@index                    | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/logs/{telescopeEntryId}          |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\LogController@show                     | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/mail                             |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\MailController@index                   | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/mail/{telescopeEntryId}          |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\MailController@show                    | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/mail/{telescopeEntryId}/download |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\MailEmlController@show                 | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/mail/{telescopeEntryId}/preview  |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\MailHtmlController@show                | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/models                           |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\ModelsController@index                 | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/models/{telescopeEntryId}        |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\ModelsController@show                  | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/monitored-tags                   |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\MonitoredTagController@store           | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/monitored-tags                   |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\MonitoredTagController@index           | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/monitored-tags/delete            |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\MonitoredTagController@destroy         | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/notifications                    |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\NotificationsController@index          | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/notifications/{telescopeEntryId} |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\NotificationsController@show           | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/queries                          |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\QueriesController@index                | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/queries/{telescopeEntryId}       |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\QueriesController@show                 | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/redis                            |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\RedisController@index                  | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/redis/{telescopeEntryId}         |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\RedisController@show                   | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/requests                         |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\RequestsController@index               | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/requests/{telescopeEntryId}      |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\RequestsController@show                | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/schedule                         |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\ScheduleController@index               | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/schedule/{telescopeEntryId}      |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\ScheduleController@show                | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/toggle-recording                 |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\RecordingController@toggle             | telescope  |
|        | POST     | telescope/telescope-api/views                            |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\ViewsController@index                  | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/telescope-api/views/{telescopeEntryId}         |                                   | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\ViewsController@show                   | telescope  |
|        | GET|HEAD | telescope/{view?}                                        | telescope                         | Laravel\Telescope\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                   | telescope  |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list` in your terminal so see the list of available routes

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of the command: `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Done, both routes seem to be missing from the output while login does show up.

Comment: Then you see why it's returning 404. Are all routes in the same route file? Also, do `php artisan route:clear` and run the list command again if the missing routes appear

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` did the trick, they now show up on the route list and I'm able to consume them! Could you post this as an answer so I can verify it?

Comment: Posted it as an answr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new routes are missing probably because Laravel is serving the cached routes. One quick way to verify this is to run `php artisan route:list`.

If the routes are not there, that confirms the theory. The solution is to run `php artisan route:clear` which tells laravel to clear the route cache, so routes can be fetched freshly from the route files.

After doing that, run `php artisan route:list` again. The missing routes should show up now and be accessible.

Comment: Okay, this does the trick but something odd's happening. After consuming the API just once it disappears from route:list and I have to do a clear again for it to show up and consume it again, then the cycle repeats. Why would that happen?

Comment: That's strange. Might I ask what version of laravel you're using? I'm suspecting the laravel telescope package

Comment: In addition to the cache issue, it's a good idea to pass the token in the header as an Authorization key.

Comment: I'm using Laravel version 6.13.1, and yes I'm passing the token in the Authorization field. Made a mistake on the OP, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I'm not sure of what might be the issue. Run, `php artisan route:clear`, then `php artisan route:cache`. Now, try consuming the API twice if it'll work both times